# Mongoose relationship multiple to one

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have a problem, more precisely i don't understand one thing with monggose and relationship.

I have one collection "Athletes" :

```
var athletesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
regionName : String,
age : Number,
overallScore : Number,
scores : {
    ordinnal : String,
    ordinnal2 : String,
    ordinnal3: String,
    ordinnal4: String,
    ordinnal5:String
}
})
```

I have another collection "Regions"

```
var regionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
athletes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Athletes' }]
})
```

One athlete have a region but a region have multiple athletes. I don't understand how is that possible, when i create an athlete the model region knows if it's on this region or this region.

i had this to my server.js :

```
Athletes.find({name : datas.name}, function(err, name){
        if(name == ""){
            Athletes.create(datas, function(err, ath){
                   if(err || ath.name){
                       console.log(err)
                   }
                   Regions.create(regionName, function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                })
           })

        }
    })
```

I check before create a new user if is not in the database, is not i create the athlete, but i don't know how to had his region in the Region model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier for you to reverse this. Have regions only having the name. And then add regionId on the Athlete model:

```
region: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Regions',
  index: true,
}
```

Then any time you update an Athlete, you're only updating this, athlete, object. Alternatively, dealing with arrays is not as simple.

With this you can query (and populate), e.g. all athletes from given regions:

```
Athletes.find({ region: [region1, region2]})
  .populate('region')
```

Now, updating region name is simplified, you do it in one place, not on all athlete instances.

There are more complex scenarios where you want to be querying things by various criteria, but most of the times, this would be the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fetch the data from an API, in the data for Athletes, the region is indicate for each athletes. But i want to create a database with Regions including each athlete for each region. It permit me to have unique regions and do some charts with it.

Comment: You can still do it with just this. If you look into aggregation, even if yo ask another question, about how to aggregate certain results, group by region, sort, project and all the other stuff, you'll probably get good feeling on what you can achieve.